# Google FusionTable - Google API for .Net

Tags: google-fusion-tables, google-api-dotnet-client

We are trying to access/update a google fusion table using the Google Api for .Net. We downloaded the .Net API and below is the code. We are able to get table information, but not execute any sql queries. All of them are returning error “Forbidden [403]”. Please review and point out our error:

This is the error message:

```
{
"error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Forbidden"
}
}
```

Below is the Code:

```
    using Google.Apis.Auth;
    using Google.Apis.Fusiontables;
    using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
    using Google.Apis.Fusiontables.v2;
    using Google.Apis.Services;
    using Google.Apis.Fusiontables.v2.Data;

    var tableID = "TABLE ID";
    var serviceAccountEmail = "id@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
    var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"..\App_Data\API Project-d000b00dd0b0.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

    ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
       new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
       {
           Scopes = new[] { FusiontablesService.Scope.Fusiontables }
       }.FromCertificate(certificate));

    FusiontablesService fusiontablesService = new FusiontablesService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName="Test"
    });

    Table tableData = fusiontablesService.Table.Get(tableID).Execute();  **//This code executes fine and we get back the table info(all column names).**

    Try  **//The Execute query throws error ‘403 – Forbidden’** 
    {
        string query = "delete from " + tableID + " where ROWID = '407';";                
        var response = fusiontablesService.Query.Sql(query).Execute();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogMessageToFile(ex.ToString());
    }

    Try **//The Execute query throws error ‘403 – Forbidden’**
    {
        string query = "update " + tableID + " SET Name = 'OU Pharmacy', Address = '1200 N Phillips Suite 2100 Oklahoma City OK 73104', Coordinates = '35.4792635,-97.4976772', lat = '35.4792635', lng = '-97.4976772', Phone = '405-271-2156', SFlg = '1', Marker = 'red_blank', Type = 'IIAS' where ROWID = '422';";
        var response = fusiontablesService.Query.Sql(query).Execute();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogMessageToFile(ex.ToString());
    }

    Try **//The Execute query throws error ‘403 – Forbidden’**
    {
        string query = "insert into " + tableID + " (Lid, Name, Address, Coordinates, lat, lng, Phone, SFlg, Type, Marker) values ('10','Bell Pharmacy','113 Boyer Ave. P.O. Box 888 Lincoln AR 72744','35.9493900,-94.4242120','35.9493900','-94.4242120','','1','NTY','grn_blank');";
        var response = fusiontablesService.Query.Sql(query).Execute();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogMessageToFile(ex.ToString());
    }
```

Thanks,
Arun

Answer (score 1):

I never use fusion-tables but in general, for access google data using a service account you need also to enable required permission to the service account.

In order to enable permission you need to logon using an administrative account, then using the [administrator console](https://admin.google.com/AdminHome) you can add desired permission using Security->(show more)Advanced->Manage API client access (see also [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106)). [Here](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using#auth) you can find the permission you need to grand.